# Como manter o valor da variavel dentro do for usando promessa?

Tags: javascript, angular

Tenho o seguinte `for`:

```js
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.d.sections.length; i++) {
      if($scope.d.sections[i].uid) {
        if ($scope.d.sections[i].title != $scope.d.sections[i].oldTitle) {
          var uid = $scope.d.sections[i].uid;
          var title = $scope.d.sections[i].title;
          Page.updateSection(uid, {title: title}).then(function (data){
            $scope.d.sections[i].oldTitle = title;
          });
        }
      } else {
        if ($scope.d.sections[i].title != 'Add Section') {
          var data = {
            title: $scope.d.sections[i].title,
            pagearticle: $stateParams.uid,
          }
          Page.addSection(data).then(function (data){
            $scope.d.sections[i] = data; //<--------
          })
        }
      }
    }
```

A função `Page.addSection` e `Page.updateSection` são requisições com promessas. O problema é o seguinte, se a promessa demorar o valor do i dentro da atribução: `$scope.d.sections[i] = data;` vai ser diferente do que eu preciso, pois o `for` já vai ter acabado.

Pórem fui esperto e fiz assim:

```js
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.d.sections.length; i++) {
      if($scope.d.sections[i].uid) {
        if ($scope.d.sections[i].title != $scope.d.sections[i].oldTitle) {
          var uid = $scope.d.sections[i].uid;
          var title = $scope.d.sections[i].title;
          var ii = i;
          Page.updateSection(uid, {title: title}).then(function (data){
            $scope.d.sections[ii].oldTitle = title;
          });
        }
      } else {
        if ($scope.d.sections[i].title != 'Add Section') {
          var data = {
            title: $scope.d.sections[i].title,
            pagearticle: $stateParams.uid,
          }
          var ii = i;
          Page.addSection(data).then(function (data){
            $scope.d.sections[ii] = data; // <------
          })
        }
      }
```

Coloquei o valor do `i` dentro de `ii`. Apesar de funcionar eu penso que não é a melhor maneira de fazer isso. ENtão tentei com `forEach`:

```js
    $scope.d.sections.forEach(function(element) {
      if(element.uid) {
        if (element.title != element.oldTitle) {
          var uid = element.uid;
          var title = element.title;
          Page.updateSection(uid, {title: title}).then(function (data){
            element.oldTitle = title;
          });
        }
      } else {
        if (element.title != 'Add Section') {
          var data = {
            title: element.title,
            pagearticle: $stateParams.uid,
          }
          Page.addSection(data).then(function (data){
            element = data; //<---------
          })
        }
      }
    })
```

Porém a atribuição `element = data;` não atualiza o valor para `$scope.d.sections`.

Há outra forma de fazer essa atribução sem eu precisar criar uma variavel para o `i`?

Comment: Qual o código das funções "updateSection" e "addSection"?

Answer (score 0):

Altere as funções "updateSection" e "addSection" para que as mesmas recebam como parâmetro o valor de i.

Fazendo isso você terá acesso a cópia do valor de i nas promessas utilizadas em cada função.